# how to call String array method in main in c#

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I don't understand why this isn't working. i am getting Error is subjects() in main as mentioned below.

My code is the following:

```
class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {string sub;
           // string brd;
            brd = board();
            sub = subjects(); // Error
            //Console.WriteLine(brd);
            Console.WriteLine(sub);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static string[] subjects()
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter How many Subject Do you Want to input");
        int limit = System.Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string[] Subjects = new string[limit];
            int[] index = new int[limit];
            for (limit = 0; limit <= index.Length; limit++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Subject Name " + limit + 1);
                Subjects[limit] = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            return Subjects;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: When posting a question you shall format your code for easy reading (respect C# conventions), you shall give us the exact error message from the compiler in a distinct way and you should pin point it in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to /**/ comment

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sub; /*1. Remove this line*/
        // string brd;
        brd = board();
        sub = subjects(); /*2. string[] sub = subjects();*/
        //Console.WriteLine(brd);
        Console.WriteLine(sub);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static string[] subjects()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter How many Subject Do you Want to input");
        int limit = System.Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string[] Subjects = new string[limit];
        int[] index = new int[limit]; /*3. Remove this line -> Redundant*/
        /*4. Change variable `limit` to `i`*/
        for (int i = 0; i <= limit; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Subject Name " + i + 1);
            Subjects[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return Subjects;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope that this is a bad approach of answering, add correct answer in code and give explanations. your code still show the errors that are mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 string[] sub = subjects();
```

Instead of this:

```
string sub;
sub = subjects();
```

Because you are getting a string of array and passing it to a normal string.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `sub` as string (`string sub`) but the method `subjects is returning a string array. So`sub`is not able to hold the return value from that method. you have to change the return type of`sub`from string to`string[]`. That means the declaration should be like this:

```
string[] sub = subjects();
```

Or in much easier way you can make it like this:

```
var sub = subjects();
```

So the compiler will automatically choose the return type based on the return value from that method. If you are confused about the datatype in such assignments you can `var` let compiler decide the datatype based on the values.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is not any Error in the code but in run time error compiler is not printing (sub)
Console.WriteLine(sub);
Console.ReadLine();